# Create a stored procedure that combining with multiple tables into current table

Tags: c#, sql-server

Please help me. Im a beginner.

I already have a table name SummaryTable, from this table I want to create a stored procedure that pull the information from that tables into SummaryTable.

BillNo = BillNo  (TxBillItem Table)

AccNo = AccNo (TxBillItem Table)

TransactionDate = TxDate (TxBill Table)

Station = referenceCode (Component Table)

Amount = Amount (TxBillItem Table)

PaymentId = PaymentTypeId (TxBillPayment Table)

ReceiptNo = ReferenceNo (TxBillPayment Table)

Status = status  (TxBill Table)

VOTNo = RevenueCode (TxBillItem Table)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| BillNo | AccNo | TransactionDate | Station | Amount | PaymentId | ReceiptNo | Status | VOTNo |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

[You may refer the Tables in this img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7pQS.png)

Comment: You could improve this question by adding sample data from each of your tables and expected result to the question as text(or to sqlfiddle) together with what you have tried so far. Also why do you think you need a stored procedure to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are attempting to return values as if they were a table you may want to look into creating and using a VIEW.

if you are attempting to take values and put them into a table you may want to look into the INSERT INTO statement.

I hope that you are successful